# Tracking multiple domain names with the same portal software in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

We provide a portal service to our customers, with different domains but with identical structure. It's really the same web site, deployed on different servers, with different configuration and content.

Ex:

- `aaa.example.com/ERM/Person/Edit/23`
- `bbb.example.net/ERM/Person/Edit/23`

I would like to be able to track each site independently as well as aggregate the statistics for all customers.

Example analysis questions:

- Which page is most used by Customer1?
- What is the loading time on a specific page for only Customer2?
- What is the loading time on a specific page for *all customers*?

How would I setup my Google Analytics trackers for this? One tracking id? Multiple ids? Different views? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see an aggregate view, you *have to* use a **single tracking id**.   There is no way in Google analytics to combine the stats from multiple trackers.

You can view the stats from individual domains that use the same tracking ID in Google Analytics.  To do so, you can apply "segments".   Create a new segment.  Use the advanced conditions to set the hostname for the site you want to view individually.

[image]

When only this segment is applied, all of the reports will show only the data for that particular host name.

Comparing the different hostnames on a single graph can be done as well, but the proceedure for doing so is very convoluted.   Me website has a bunch of subdomains that I want to compare, so I wrote a blog post about how to get the graph:  http://blog.ostermiller.org/analytics-subdomain/   Comparing different domain names with the same tracker should be exactly the same as comparing different subdomains since it triggers on hostname.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ostermiller.org](http://blog.ostermiller.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/google-analytics-subdomain-graph-300x159.png))</sub>